# Blazor WASM .NET Core Hosted .NET5: Missing ClientId: Can't get Google authentication working as per the example for Google Authentication

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I've created a new solution using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.9.2. using .NET5.

I created it using DotNetCLI with command

```
dotnet new blazorwasm -au Individual -ho -o HostingDashboard
```

I've added the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google Nuget package to the Server project.
In my Server project Startup.cs file, I have the following ConfigureServices code:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
                ;

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt()
                ;

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = Configuration["Google:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];
                    options.AuthorizationEndpoint += "?prompt=select_account";
                });
```

For my program.cs file (Server Project) I have:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, builder) => 
            {
                if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    builder.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
                }
            });
    }
```

I've added to my secrets the following:

```
PM> dotnet user-secrets list
Google:ClientSecret = xxxxxx
Google:ClientId = xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

where the xxxx is obviously obfuscated stuff, but copied from our Google console...
I've also tried using secrets named "Authentication:Google:ClientId", etc, but that does not change the results.

Everytime I try to run in debug, I get the following error page:

```
System.ArgumentException: The 'ClientId' option must be provided. (Parameter 'ClientId')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthOptions.Validate()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.Validate(String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.<AddSchemeHelper>b__1(TOptions o)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ValidateOptions`1.Validate(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.FederatedSignoutAuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this would be appreciated. Or perhaps, this is just not possible with Blazorwasm and .NET5?

Comment: The error is clear. The `ClientId` property is missing. Are you sure it's loaded? What does `Configuration["Google:ClientId"];` return ? Have you stored that setting in a config file?

Comment: Well, yes. But I've added the ClientId, ClientSecret to the secrets vault as directed by the example in the server project. The command "dotnet user-secrets list" confirms they are there.

Yet the identityserver/authentication libraries cannot find them as the code examples indicate that they should be able to do, automagically...

Comment: So, I changed to add the values to my appsetttings.Development.json file, and through debug, I can confirm that the values exist and match what the Google Console provides.

However, now I get a new error from IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions after trying to load a page:





System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.<>c.<AddSigningCredentials>b__10_2(IServiceProvider sp)